# Background image technique

Tags: css, image, background

Is there any tehnical term for the full-image centered technique?
Example: topgear.com, http://safe.tumblr.com/theme/preview/979, and many others which I don't recall.

Comment: I have no idea what you are talking about.

Comment: do you mean the background applied to element with `id="wrap"`? That's simply `background:url("http://static.tumblr.com/xsp9wak/xAOkloi15/background-top.jpg") no-repeat scroll center top transparent;`

Comment: I'd call it a background image or a 'watermark' image - however the latter would tend to imply that the image is rather less obtrusive.

Answer (score 2):

You can either create a large size image (e.g. `2000px` width/height) and set it as a background with `background-position: 50% 50%`. Or you can add an `<img src="background.jpg" width="100%" height="100%" />` at the the `body` tag and position it absolutely that it will be stretched according page size.

Comment: Backround-position: 50% 50% does not center it vertically and horizontally. It sets the starting point of the bg to the center of the screen.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it has a specific name. Here's an article with some state-of-the-art tricks:

http://www.alistapart.com/articles/supersize-that-background-please/

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was talking about

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so, no. The image is just placed inside the master div (in this case #wrap). It has some right and left padding to it so it will be set in the exact middle. You can however use an image with the same size as the master div.

Here is the code that website uses:

```
#wrap {

background: url("http://static.tumblr.com/xsp9wak/xAOkloi15/background-top.jpg") no-repeat scroll center top transparent;
margin: 0 auto;
overflow: hidden;
padding-left: 28px;
padding-right: 28px;
position: relative;
width: 905px;
```

PS: There are many ways to accomplish this.

Answer (score -1):

Don't you mean lightbox technique? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lightbox_%28JavaScript%29